# Union summary statistics with query result in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a PostgreSQL table that stores readings from power meters. I use SQLAlchemy and psycopg2 to query the database. Some large sites can have multiple power meters, and I have a query that returns timestamped data, aggregated by facility:

Raw table:

```
timestamp | meter_id | facility_id | reading
  1:00:00 |        1 |           1 |     1.0
  1:00:00 |        2 |           1 |     1.5
  1:00:00 |        3 |           2 |     2.1
  1:00:30 |        1 |           1 |     1.1
  1:00:30 |        2 |           1 |     1.6
  1:00:30 |        3 |           2 |     2.2
```

Aggregated:

```
timestamp | facility_1 | facility_2
  1:00:00 |        2.5 |       2.1
  1:00:30 |        2.7 |       2.2
```

The query I use for this looks like this:

```
SELECT
    reading.timestamp,
    sum(reading.reading) FILTER (WHERE reading.facility_id = 1) as facility_1,
    sum(reading.reading) FILTER (WHERE reading.facility_id = 2) as facility_2
FROM reading
GROUP BY reading.timestamp
WHERE
    reading.timestamp >= 1:00:00 AND reading.timestamp < 1:01:00
    AND reading.facility_id IN 1, 2
```

(Sorry for any SQL errors, I've simplified the problem a little for clarity). I often need to downsample the data for display, which I do by wrapping the above query in a FROM...AS... clause and binning the data into larger time intervals. Before doing that, though, I'd like to grab some summary statistics from my derived "facilities" table--min reading, max reading, avg reading, etc., similar to what's described in [this blog post](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-summary-statistics.html). However, I can't figure out how to use SQLALchemy to get this data--I keep getting psycopg2 errors from the resulting SQL. My SQLAlchemy version of the above query is:

```
selects = [Reading.timestamp,
    sqlalchemy.func.sum(Reading.reading).filter(Reading.facility_id==1),
    sqlalchemy.func.sum(Reading.reading).filter(Reading.facility_id==2)
]
base_query = db.session.query(*selects). \
    group_by(Reading.timestamp). \
    filter(Reading.facility_id.in_([1, 2])). \
    filter(and_(Reading.timestamp>=start_time, Reading.timestamp<=end_time)). \
    order_by(Reading.timestamp)
```

I can get summary statistics with something like this:

```
subq = base_query.subquery()
avg_selects = [sqlalchemy.func.avg(col) for col in subq.columns]
avg_query = db.session.query(*avg_selects)
```

Which will return a single row with the average of all columns from my original query. However, I can't figure out how to get this with my original query--I end up having to get the statistics separately, which feel like a huge waste (these queries can go over many rows). Queries like the one below always return errors:

```
all = base_query.union(avg_query).all()

ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "UNION"
LINE 4: ...reading.timestamp ORDER BY reading.timestamp UNION SELE...
```

I feel like my understanding of SQLAlchemy's subquery system is weak, but I haven't been able to make headway from the subquery tutorial in SQLAlchemy's documentation. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was right in the error message--I needed to remove the ORDER BY clause from the subquery to outside of the union operation and move it outside of the UNION. I am using dummy timestamps for the summary statistics to ensure that they are at the top of the query result in a predictable order after ordering on timestamp. The following code works:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression, func
from datetime import datetime
from models import Reading

selects = [Reading.timestamp.label("timestamp_"),
    func.sum(Reading.reading).filter(Reading.facility_id==1),
    func.sum(Reading.reading).filter(Reading.facility_id==2)
]

base_query = db.session.query(*selects). \
    group_by(Reading.timestamp). \
    filter(Reading.facility_id.in_([1, 2])). \
    filter(and_(Reading.timestamp>=start_time, Reading.timestamp<=end_time))

subq = base_query.subquery()

avg_selects = [expression.bindparam('dummy_date', datetime(1980, 1, 1)).label("timestamp_")
avg_selects += [func.avg(col) for col in subq.columns[1:]
avg_query = db.session.query(*avg_selects)

full_query = base_query.union(avg_query).order_by(asc("timestamp_"))
```

I would be happy to hear more graceful ways of accomplishing this. The query is wrapped in a function that takes arbitrary lists of facility IDs; the "columns" trick is the only way I've figured out to make it work with arbitrary columns (as long as the first column is always timestamps).